# auto- remove charters that are not valid

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

need to make sure the input fields in the client side are valid, but I want to prevent a lot of characters (I have a lot of condition for the input filed to be valid.) My javascript is not currently working, but I had an idea for a simpler method: the javascript will auto remove invalid characters as user writes. For example "d#an" will be auto fixed to "dan"

I have a wrote a JS method that works in "the old way" of taking the input filed checking them, and returning true or false

but this is not my target.
 the invail charcters are: capital letters (if they are not at the start) special charters,name that is shorter than tow letter(in this case the system will auto add tow letters) a name without "ouiea" (the system will auto add one of this randomly) and a non English letters like: שלום –

Comment: Do you want the new method to do all current verification? or there is only a list of invalid characters? What are those invalid characters?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour i want the new one. the invail charcters are: capital letters (if they are not at the start) special charters,name that is shorter than tow letter(in this case the system will auto add tow letters) a name without "ouiea" (the system will auto add one of this randomly) and a non English letters like: שלום

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a jobmate figre it. javascript:

```
   function Valid(input)
     {

    var str = /[^a-z]/gi;
    input.value = input.value.replace(str, "");
    }
```

html:

```
    <form>
     <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onkeyup="Valid(this)" />
    </form>
```